# jQuery - As soon as a element is visible - Like Document.Ready

Tags: jquery

with jQuery is there a way to say, instead of doc ready, as soon as this item is visible do XXXXXXX?

Reason why is I have an app with 3 panels. The first panel by default is hidden and has a carousel. The carousel breaks if it is initiated when not visible. So I'd like to say as soon as the carousel or the div is visible, initiate the carousel.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to handle this would be to use a certain method to make the carousel visible, and then trigger an "event" (you could use jQuery's custom event stuff here, but there's no real need to, a simple function call will work just as well).

For example:

```
function showCarousel() {
    $("#carousel").show();
    carouselShowEvent();
}
function carouselShowEvent() {
    initiateCarousel();
}
```

If for some odd reason you can't do that, you could always use a window.setInterval to periodically check whether it's visible ... but that's almost certainly the wrong way to go about it.

```
// Don't do this
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if ($("#carousel").is(":visible")) {
        initiateCarousel();
        interval.clearInterval();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks but what does the function showCarousel do? I'm not following how that solves the problem?

Comment: What about binding to the DIV where the Carousel lives. and saying. onVisible initiate Carousel, is that doable?

Comment: The function showCarousel is meant to be whatever function you are calling to make the carousel appear (it's not just magically going from hidden to visible right?).  So the idea is you already have some place, or maybe multiple places, that can show the carousel.  If there are multiple places, refactor them all to have a single function that they all call, then trigger your "event" in that function (if there's only one place, you can just add the trigger there).

Comment: There is no "onVisible" defined in JS, so you can't do that (without making one via setInterval, or overriding $.fn.show, or doing something equally hacky).

Comment: Thanks but that won't work. bec while it will work the first time, if you then switch panels, and then go back to the carousel panel, it's now broken. It needs to turn on everytime it's visible

Comment: So how are you "going back" to the carousel panel?  Whatever function does that will need to trigger carouselShowEvent.